# crystal reports using one column for multiple formulas

Tags: crystal-reports

Ok....I will try to explain this as best as I can....
I have an SQL query that is pulling back the correct data that I need for a report. 
This is something of what it looks like

```
sample    componentname       enteredvalue  
C1234-1   Am-241 Activity     2.35E+001
C1234-1   Am-241 2s TPU       3.26E-002
C1234-1   Am-241 1s TPU       3.22E-002      
C1234-1   U-238 Activity      6.32E-001
C1234-1   U-238 2s TPU        1.23E+002
C1234-1   U-238 1s TPU        2.00E+001
```

I need to take the componentname and the enteredvalue associated with that componentname and display it horizontally  without blanks.
Something like this

```
componentname    activity    2s TPU     1s TPU    
Am-241           2.35E+001   3.26E-002  3.22E-002
U-238            6.32E+002   1.23E+002  2.00E+001
```

I've tried approaching this multiple different ways and I still cannot figure it out. I've tried using formulas to bring back the columns but I keep getting blanks.

Any insight would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you post your formulas?

Comment: Here is one of the formulas. It's just calling back the componentname for whatever I declare. `if {Command.SubstanceCode} = 'NESHAP-AFC' then {Command_1.ComponentName} = 'U-233/234 2s TPU' or {Command_1.ComponentName} = 'U-238 2s TPU' or {Command_1.ComponentName} = 'Pu-238 2s TPU' or {Command_1.ComponentName} = 'Pu-239/240 2s TPU' or {Command_1.ComponentName} = 'Am-241 2s TPU' `

This leaves blanks wherever the componentnames aren't exact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the first and second parts of the Component Name and then store them in variables if you want to use them all on the same line in the report. You'll also need to group by the first part of the component name (like "U-238"), which you can do with the formula `split({table.component_name}," ",2)[1]`

Now you'll have Group Header, Details, and Group Footer sections; Each needs their own formula to keep track of the values you want to display.

```
// Initialize the variables in the Group Header
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar activity_value := "";
stringvar TwoS_value := "";
stringvar OneS_value := "";

// Update the variables in the Details section
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar activity_value;
stringvar TwoS_value;
stringvar OneS_value;

select split({table.component_name}," ",2)[2]
case "Activity" : activity_value := {table.entered_value};
case "2s TPU" : TwoS_value := {table.entered_value};
case "1s TPU" : OneS_value := {table.entered_value};

// Display the variables in the Group Footer (one formula for each variable)
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar activity_value
```

Alternatively, you could also play around with using the two formulas that split the component name in a crosstab. So, for example, you could make the rows of the crosstab the first half of the component name and the columns would then be the second half.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ryan!

However, when I try the group formula it says that A variable name is expected here on the stringvar 2s_value line.

I've been working with crystal reports for about 2 months now and am fairly new still.

Comment: Woops, CR doesn't like when you start variable names with numbers. I'll fix the solution.